# Is it possible to disable esc/F11 key during full screen mode of webpage, programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to disable esc/F11 key during full screen mode of webpage, programmatically? I need to have an exit button within the webpage to exit from fullscreen mode, but need to prevent to come outside the fullscreen mode using other funcationality of windows(like esc, F11, etc.). Please help me if anyone have any idea about this.

Comment: You can't do that.  The user will always have full control over the browser.

Comment: Not sure if I'd say you can't, I've seen a web application by Red Prairie override the F3 key. Doesn't work well. Half the time I walk by those computers at work they have the IE search dialog open.

Comment: Even if you *can* do it, you should probably consider if you really *want* to do it. Particularly since the browser is still going to tell the user that they can do it. (When they go fullscreen most browsers will show the user a prompt saying "press ESC to exit fullscreen") If you disable that all you're really achieving is a frustrating user experience. So unless you have a *really* good reason for doing so (unlikely) you shouldn't mess with your users expectations.

Comment: If the browser is started in kiosk mode, the user might not be able to f11 out of it.  eg, `chrome.exe --kiosk http://stackoverflow.com` (close other chrome instances before trying)

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can disable it listening to the keydown event:

```js
$(document).on("keydown",function(ev){
 console.log(ev.keyCode);
 if(ev.keyCode===27||ev.keyCode===122) return false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

keycode 27 stands for the ESC key and 122 for the F11. This was tested in chrome, maybe for other browsers can be other number

Comment: It is not possible to catch the Esc key in full screen mode.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.key == "F11") e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That's works when you aren't in full screen in google chrome but  when you are in full screen doesn't work.