# How to disable fullscreen when press f11 on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Iam writing an application and it need f11 key as a shortcut to do some tasks. However, if User is focusing on chrome and press f11, the chrome will fullscreen. And they will press f11 again to exit fullscreen, that will make my app run task twice. 
Can I disable fullscreen when press f11 on chrome?
Sorry for my English. Thank you!

Comment: Just interrupt your event processing. event.preventDefault()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784902/is-it-possible-to-disable-esc-f11-key-during-full-screen-mode-of-webpage-progra

Comment: No men. Iam talking about google chrome, not javascript or website. Maybe there is an option in chrome or I have to write an extension?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @ChrisP Not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

In real world (maybe) using the

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.key == "F11") {e.preventDefault()};
});
```

could solve the problem.

It prevents the default run action for opening full screen but not for closing it (using google chrome).